# brightcove not showing when rendered (not page refresh - plain Backbone.js View re-render)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, brightcove

TLDR; The video player doesn't show on re-render (Backbone View)

Is there some global state brightcove keeps?

I'm using backbone.js and rendering the page using a backbone View with this jst.ejs template. It works perfectly the first time around. But if I navigate to next page and then back, it doesn't show anymore.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js"></script>
<script>
  window.BCVideo = BCVideoFunction(); //BCVideoFunction as module pattern.
</script>

<object id="bc_experience" class="BrightcoveExperience">
  <param name="includeAPI" value="true" />
  <param name="templateLoadHandler" value="BCVideo.onTemplateLoad" />
  <param name="templateReadyHandler" value="BCVideo.onTemplateReady" />
  <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
  <param name="width" value="100%" />
  <param name="height" value="100%" />
  <param name="playerID" value="1426444499001" />
  <param name="playerKey" value="AQ~~,AAABTAHETAE~,G1RKcv5og48msI78DncnAb9MEySkUi_b" />
  <param name="isVid" value="true" />
  <param name="isUI" value="true" />
  <param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>
  <param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true" />
  <param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>
  <param name="@videoPlayer" value="<%= variables.video_id %>" />
</object>
```

after rerender (second visit), I can see the object exists

```
 > window.bc_experience  `  
   <object type=​"application/​x-shockwave-flash" data=​"http:​/​/​c.brightcove.com ...
 # window.bc_experience.remove() doesn't help
```

Removing it from the dom doesn't help.
Yeah... Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using `<script>` tags inside your template. The external script should definitely be outside of your template and you can replace the following:

```
<script>
  window.BCVideo = BCVideoFunction(); //BCVideoFunction as module pattern.
</script>
```

With:

```
<% window.BCVideo = BCVideoFunction(); %>
```

Comment: this should be a comment, you are not addressing the problem. Or are you? My apologies if you are, please elaborate.